# Only enable KCFinder if php variable set

Tags: php, kcfinder

I'm using KCFinder to let users upload files to my website. However, anyone can upload files to my server atm by typing `mysite.com/kcfinder/browse.php`. I want users only to be able to use KCFinder iff an variable called `$permitted` is set on the page they came from. How would I implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please see SESSION INTEGRATION in docs of KCFinder

http://kcfinder.sunhater.com/docs/integrate#session

by setting SESSION var like this

```
$_SESSION['KCFINDER'] = array();
$_SESSION['KCFINDER']['disabled'] = false;
```

you will enable the KCFINDER. Do this only for authenticated users and you should be ok.

Comment: I saw that page earlier, but I must have misread something. Thanx!

Answer (score 0):

How about set a cookie in whatever area authorizes access to KCFinder, and use .htaccess to set a cookie requirement for the kcfinder directory?

Cookies are set with the setcookie function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

In your .htaccess, add:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !cookie-name=COOKIE_NAME_HERE [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /login/ [NC,L]
```

Where COOKIE_NAME_HERE is your cookie's name, and /login/ is whatever path you want users to go to should they try to access KCFinder without authorization.